# Tensorflow: how to evaluate test data with persistence session?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Recently, I encountered a tensorflow evaluation question. My demand is that I want to use a trained network to evaluate some *dynamic testing data*.

*The dynamic testing data* means that I initially just have one testing data, and the second testing data will be generated subsequently according to the evaluation result of the first testing data.

**A simple solution is I can write a evaluation function to evaluate testing data one by one such as**

```
def evaluation(testing_data):
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, params['height'], params['width'], params['depth']])
    logits = inference(input)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir + '/'))
        prediction = self.session.run([logits['pred']], feed_dict={input: testing_data})
    return prediction
```

However, this solution is extremely slow since I need to initialize the Tensorflow Graph once when I call this function (Obviously, the graph only need to be initialized one time, because I don't change any parameters or something else of the trained network).

**In order to improve the efficiency, I rewrite the evaluation function as below.**

```
def new_evaluation(testing_data, first_initialize):
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, params['height'], params['width'], params['depth']])
    if first_initialize:
        logits = inference(input)
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        # use a global variable to save session
        global_session = tf.Session()   
        saver.restore(global_session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir + '/'))
        prediction = global_session.run([logits['pred']], feed_dict={input: testing_data})
    else:
        prediction = global_session.run([logits['pred']], feed_dict={input: testing_data})
    return prediction 
# I will manually close the global session when I finish all of jobs.
```

The intention of new_evaluation function is obvious:

1. If it is the first time to evaluate, we create tensorflow inference graph and restore trained parameters.
2. If we already have initialized session, we directly use it to evaluate new testing data.

**Problem:**

This new_evaluation function works fine when it goes to *first_initialize* branch, but it pop up some errors when I call it second time. Here is the log

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,256,256,3]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,256,256,3], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: prediction/_431 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1275_prediction", tensor_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

This log seems tell us the data type is inconsistent. However, the second testing data has the same type and shape with the first testing data.

Why the first one works but the second one crash?

Any ideas or better solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to efficiently solve this problem. I provide my solution here in case others need it.

We can use coroutine to save session context after the first initialization. Here is the code

```
def evaluation(self, checkpoint_dir):
    input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.params['height'], self.params['width'], self.params['depth']])
    logits = inference(input)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir + '/'))
        while not global_close:
            prediction = sess.run([self.pred], feed_dict={input: global_input})
            yield prediction
# we have two global variables. global_close control the exit and global_input save the input


def your_task_process():
    global_close = False
    evaluator = evaluation(checkpoint_dir)  # create a generator

    # do you stuff

    global_input = your_input1      # assign a testing data
    inference_value1 = next(evaluator)

    # do you stuff

    global_input = your_input2      # assign the second testing data
    inference_value2 = next(evaluator)

    ...

    # when finish, terminate the generator
    global_close = True
    next(evaluator)
```